# Magento 2 Cannot modify header

Tags: magento2

`magento 2 multistore  issues Warning:`

Cannot modify header information - headers already sent path is ( `/home/y2way/public_html/microzu2/app/bootstrap.php:1`)

Comment: magento 2 multistore issues Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/y2way/public_html/microzu2/app/bootstrap.php:1) .Please help me

Comment: please answer me

Comment: Remove space from /home/y2way/public_html/microzu2/app/bootstrap.php line 1 .

Comment: In your bootstrap.php file, make sure there is  no space before the <?php tag

Comment: Its worked for me